# Kernel design for overlapping data, launch of a seperate warp

Tags: cuda

i have a question regarding a CFD application i am trying to implement according to a [paper](http://www.serri.org/publications/Documents/Ole%20Miss%20Project%2080031%20-%20Efficient%20Shallow%20Water%20Simulations%20on%20GPUs%20-%20August%202010%20%28Brodtkorb,%20Saetra,%20Altinakar%29.pdf) i found online. this might be somewhat of a beginner question, but here it goes:

the situation is as follows:
the 2D domain gets decomposed into tiles. Each of these tiles is being processed by a block of the kernel in question. The calculations being executed are highly suited for parallel execution, as they take into account only a handfull of their neighbours (it's a shallow water application). The tiles do overlap. Each tile has 2 extra cells on each side of the domain it's supposed to calculate the result to.

[image: block setup]

on the left you see 1 block, on the right 4, with the overlap that comes with it. grey are "ghost cells" needed for the calculation. light green is the domain each block actually writed back to global memory. needless to say the whole domain is going to have more than 4 tiles.

The idea per thread goes as following:

```
(1) copy data from global memory to shared memory
__synchthreads();
(2) perform some calculations
__synchthreads();
(3) perform some more calculations
(4) write back to globabl memory
```

for the cells in the green area, the Kernel is straight forward, you copy data according to your threadId, and calculate along using your neighbours in shared memory. Because of the nature of the data dependency this does however not suffice:

> (1) has to be run on all cells (grey and green). No dependency.
>
> (2) has to be run on all green cells, and the inner rows/columns of the grey cells. Depends on neighbouring data N,S,E and W.
>
> (3) has to be run on all green cells. Depends on data from step (2) on neighbours N,S,E and W.

so here goes my question:
how does one do this without a terribly cluttered code?

all i can think of is a horrible amount of "if" statements to decide whether a thread should perform some of these steps twice, depending on his threadId.

i have considered using overlapping blocks as well (as opposed to just overlapping data), but this leads to another problem: the __synchthreads()-calls would have to be in conditional parts of the code.
Taking the kernel apart and having the steps (2)/(3) run in different kernels is not really an option either, as they produce intermediate results which can't all be written back to memory because of their number/size.

the author himself writes this (Brodtkorb et al. 2010, Efficient Shallow Water Simulations on GPUs:
Implementation, Visualization, Verification, and Validation):

> When launching our kernel, we start by reading from global memory into on-chip shared memory. In addition to the interior cells of our block, we need to use data from two neighbouring cells in each direction to fulfill the data
> dependencies of the stencil. After having read data into shared memory, we proceed by computing the one dimensional
> fluxes in the x and y directions, respectively. Using the steps illustrated in Figure 1, fluxes are computed by storing
> all values that are used by more than one thread in shared memory. We also perform calculations collectively within
> one block to avoid duplicate computations. However, because we compute the net contribution for each cell, we have
> to perform more reconstructions and flux calculations than the number of threads, complicating our kernel. **This is
> solved in our code by designating a single warp that performs the additional computations**; a strategy that yielded a
> better performance than dividing the additional computations between several warps.

so, what does he mean by designating a single warp to do these compuations, and how does one do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so, what does he mean by designating a single warp to do these compuations, and how does one do so?

You could do something like this:

```
  // work that is done by all threads in a block
  __syncthreads();  // may or may not be needed
  if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
    // work that is done only by the designated single warp
    }
```

Although that's trivially simple, insofar as the last question in your question is considered, and the highlighted paragraph, I think it's very likely what they are referring to.  I think it fits with what I'm reading here.  Furthermore I don't know of any other way to restrict work to a single warp, except by using conditionals.  They may also have chosen a single warp to take advantage of warp-synchronous behavior, which gets around the `__syncthreads();` in conditional code issue you mention earlier.

> so here goes my question: how does one do this without a terribly cluttered code?
>
> all i can think of is a horrible amount of "if" statements to decide whether a thread should perform some of these steps twice, depending on his threadId.

Actually, I don't think any sequence of ordinary "if" statements, regardless of how cluttered, could solve the problem you describe.

A typical way to solve the dependency between steps 2 and 3 that you have already mentioned is to separate the work into two ( or more) kernels.  You indicate that this is "not really an option", but as near as I can tell, what you're looking for is a global sync.  Such a concept is not well-defined in CUDA except for the kernel launch/exit points.  CUDA does not guarantee execution order among blocks in a grid.  If your block calculations in step 3 depend on *neighboring block* calculations in step 2, then in my opinion, you definitely need a global sync, and your code is going to get ugly if you don't implement it with a kernel launch.  Alternative methods such as using global semaphores or global block counters are, in my opinion, fragile and difficult to apply to general cases of widespread data dependence (where every block is dependent on neighbor calculations from the previous step).

If the neighboring calculations depend on only the data from a thin set of neighboring cells ("halo") , and not the whole neighboring block, and those cells can be computed independently, then it might be possible to have your block be expanded to include neighboring cells (i.e. overlap), effectively computing the halo regions twice between neighboring blocks,  but you've indicated you've already considered and discarded this idea.  However, I personally would want to consider the code in detail before accepting the idea that this would be rejected based entirely on difficulty with `__syncthreads();`  In my experience, people who say they can't use `__syncthreads();` due to conditional code execution haven't accurately considered all the options, at a detail code level, to make `__syncthreads();` work, even in the midst of conditional code.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. regarding the global sync: this is probably a misunderstanding due to my explanation. The blocks don't need to communicate in the step in question. they use the overlap (halo) to exactely avoid talking to each other. so that is not the problem. i did not discard this as you say, it's actually exactely what is supposed to happen. However i mean to do this by 192 threads (the number of green cells). the number of grey cells to handle is (depending whether it's step 1 or 2) 128 or 48. So i would need to map the threadIds smartly to the memoryIds. but how?

Comment: one more thing, just to be clear: what i did discard (at least for now) was the option to use a thread for every cell (including halo), therefor using 320 threads. then the blocks would overlap (not just the memory). you might be right that there is a way around putting `__synchthreads();` in conditional statements for this case by refining the algorithm. however i don't see it yet.

Comment: i have reconsidered and rewritten the kernel to use more threads, handling the `__synchthreads();` differently. thank you for your answer.